# How to `--scale` from within docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let's say I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    load-balancer:
        ...
        ...

    web-application:
        ...
        ...
```

If I want to run this with 5 replicas of `web-application`, I have to issue this command:

`docker-compose up --scale web-application=5`

Is there any way to tell Docker to do the `--scale web-application=5` bit from within the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can specify the number of replicas in docker-compose only when working in swarm mode.

See the [`deploy`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#deploy) directive.

Example:

```
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
```

From the documentation:

> This only takes effect when deploying to a swarm with
> docker stack deploy, and is ignored by docker-compose up
> and docker-compose run.

Lastly, there is some discussion about this feature (since it used to be possible) in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5586), and [here](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#scale) is the mention in the most recent compose spec.

Comment: This solution worked for me, you should use docker-compose up -d to start the docker container with his replicas.

Comment: This doesn't work with `docker-compose up -d`. It says `WARNING: Some services use the 'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration` so it only works in swarm mode? but i don't want a swarm

Answer (score 5):

I tested replicas in docker compose file, the code that worked for me is the following.
[image: docker container example with 5 replicas]

You should use docker-compose up -d to execute the configuración

You should see the next results.
[image: results.]

The results in web browser should be the following:
[image: nginx in web browser]

Comment: I remember reading that this is only possible in 'swarm' mode. Did you have to switch on anything like 'swarm' mode on your system to get this to work?

Comment: Trying this on my machine without any changes to the default install and I can confirm docker compose up -d does in fact take use of the deploy.replicas field.